# How to disable sociallite logs in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to disable sociallite logs in laravel 5, how I can do this? I tried different ways, but same result and not working it for me.

How can I do this, how can I disable log file in Laravel 5?

I just don't want to disable only (sociallite) not other logs.

Comment: *"i try diffrent ways"* - show us what have you tried

Comment: Why don't you want to disable , having log is obviously better than not ....

Comment: beacause of this error `local.ERROR:  {"exception":"[object] (Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\InvalidStateException(code: 0):  at /var/www/system/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:210)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/system/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php(67): Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\AbstractProvider->user()`
this is line 67  `$userfb = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
` i tried stateless() but same result!

Comment: 1. Show us your `stateless` code, because that error shouldn't occur with it. 2. Hiding the error doesn't *stop* the error. Your question is focused on the wrong part of the issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz you right bro i search for that error i saw this code `stateless` to fix it, i try to fix it but i can't because of that i wanna to stop log, but if you can help me thank you. what code you need? to paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add exception types to the `$dontReport` property of the exception handler class (`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`) in your project to prevent those exceptions from being logged. For example:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException
    ];
```

See Laravel's [Error Handling documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors) for more information.

Comment: it is fix my problem about day, but after that same problem!